# JavaScript: Sluggishness events? Google Chrome "Speed Tracer" extension is reporting

Tags: javascript, html, performance, google-chrome

Using Google Chromes new Speed Tracer extension to profile my app.

Appears my app is constantly reporting "**Sluggish (events) 100%**", which means the browser is blocking html rendering.

I don't understand enough how to interpreter the Speed Tracer tool to fix this issue.

Any help appreciated. My web app is: [bit.ly/7J0U](http://bit.ly/7J0U)

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem sluggish to me (Macbook 10.5.8/FF 3.5.5).  My initial thought was to direct you to some [event delegation](http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2008/07/23/javascript-event-delegation-is-easier-than-you-think/#) information, but that doesn't seem applicable after visiting your app.

Try to get a barometer for Speed Tracer's reports by running the tool on different sites and see how they compare with your own.  That may help you to get a better sense of how to interpret the reports.  Also, don't forget that these things (YSlow included) are tools not rules.